# How can I group_concat this?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm trying to get this query to work, basically its a CSV export of some products with properties spread across mutiple tables.
I managed to get everything I need exported except the additional images that a produtct might have, those are in a separate table and each image per product is a new row in that table.
Here is what I have for now

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id,
           pd.name,
           cd.name AS catname,
           pd.description,
           p.price,
           pa.text AS qty,
           p.mimage,
           ps.price AS pricespecial


    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd
    ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c
    ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
    LEFT JOIN category_description cd
    ON p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa
    ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_special ps
    ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
```

I use `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ fputcsv($f,$row);` to make the CSV. Now I need to also get the additional images in the `$row` to CSV but in that table there are multiple rows per each additional product image, some of them don't have additional images, how can I use `group_concat` or some other way to make `$row` append each of those images IF they exists per each product. The images are in column `"image_url"` like

```
product_id image_url

    22           none.jpg
    22           abcd.jpg
    22           cdfg.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to simplify it a bit.

Basically I'm using

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

then I make an array and put my rows in there like this

```
$values = array($row['product_id'],$row['name'],$row['catname'],$row['description'],etc);
```

How can I construct a foreach loop inside my while loop something like

```
foreach $row['product_id'] {
  $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(images) FROM table WHERE product_id='$row['product_id']' 
}
```

Then I believe I can get those images for each product and use them in my other array, right?